# Windows 7 - play songs contained in external hard drive Mac journaled

Tags: windows-7, macos, external-hard-drive

I have an external Mac journaled formatted hard drive containing all my music,
but Windows 7 doesn't recognize the file system, so I can not open any files contained in it.

By searching on the web I found some applications that allow me to recognize this disk,
and to navigate through the directories of the hard drive;  but if I want to open a file I must copy it to a Windows-compatible partition before I can open it.

Is there some way to play songs directly from the disk?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at MacDrive.

http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive

I've used the product for years and it will mount R/W access to any Mac format partition type for native Windows use. They have a 5-day full-feature trial period so you can make sure it's going to work for you before you consider buying it.

Comment: Nice!  Ya learn about something new every day. ;)

Comment: I've installed it, but I cant open the folders... The folders are displayed as unidentified blank file, and not as folders... Maybe because it is a TimeMachine backup?

Comment: Yes, that would likely be a problem. You didn't mention that in the original question. Is this a Time Capsule, or just a standard USB drive that you had connected to an Apple for Time Machine backups? If this is a Time Machine backup to a standard USB drive then you'll only be able to access the archived data from a Mac.

Comment: Also, if this is just a USB disk with Time Machine backups on it, [this page](http://pondini.org/TM/17.html) has info on the sum-total of options for recovering that data (**from a different Mac**). [This page explains why](http://pondini.org/TM/Works.html).